# Conditionally Supply 'Credential' Parameter to Functions

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to conditionally supply the 'Credentials' parameter, so I can condense the code by removing the second if...else statement. Any ideas?

```
$params = @{ ScriptBlock = $ScriptBlock; ArgumentList = $Parameters }

if (-not $Remote -or $ComputerName -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
    Start-Job @params -ErrorAction Stop
}
else {
    $params.Add('ComputerName',$ComputerName)
    if (-not $Parameters.Creds) {
        $ComputerName | Test-PsRemoting
        if ($CopyTool) { $CopyTool | Copy-Tool -ComputerName $ComputerName }
        Invoke-Command @params -AsJob -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    else {
        $ComputerName | Test-PsRemoting -Credential $Parameters.Creds
        if ($CopyTool) { $CopyTool | Copy-Tool -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Parameters.Creds }
        Invoke-Command @params -Credential $Parameters.Creds -AsJob -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using splatting, can't you just supply a Credentials entry in the $params hashtable  (instead of calling it Creds)?

Then, you will only supply credentials if it's in the hashtable...you don't need an "else".

That isn't quite what you want, though.

When I want to "conditionally" supply credentials parameter (or any other parameter), I create a separate hashtable that is either empty or has the Credential item (with a key of Credential), and then splat it to the cmdlet in question.

You can splat multiple hashtables, too.  So after the first "else", this:

```
   $params.Add('ComputerName',$ComputerName)
   $credHash=@{}
   if ($Parameters.Creds) { 
        $credHash=@{Credential=$parameters.Creds}
   }
   $ComputerName | Test-PsRemoting @credHash
   if ($CopyTool) { $CopyTool | Copy-Tool -ComputerName $ComputerName @credHash }
   Invoke-Command @params @credHash -AsJob -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Because if "$Parameters.Creds" is null, and I add it to the hashtable, Invoke-Command throws an error. Plus, I would still need to conditionally supply "-Credential $Parameters.Creds" to the custom functions 'Test-PsRemoting' and 'Copy-Tool'. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, or chasing something that's not there...

Comment: Ah, this is what I needed! In my attempts, I did something similar, but only declared the $credHash if creds were passed. I didn't think to declare it regardless, but populate it if creds were passed. That takes care of the errors. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  I think splatting is probably one of the most unappreciated features of PowerShell.  This is a good application of it.

Comment: Definitely! Using this method, I was able to trim over 50 lines of fat from my script. Thanks again.